# what are the DB.Properties(??) variables? Specifically setting the default ribbon

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access 2007 app that I'm updating to be able to run on both 2007 and 2010.  In 2007 I use the form ribbon property, but with 2010 I've needed to make a default ribbon that turns off the backstage.  I've done that but the app needs too set it as default when it detects that it is running on 2010 instead of 2007.  The Load custom UI does not work.  It loads it but it does not set a ribbon as default.   I know I can set the default start up form and other properties with the database.properties function.  But I need to know the property name for the application default ribbon.  Anyone know the property names?

Answer (score 2):

I think the name of the Database Property your looking for is: CustomRibbonId

Here's some code to output a list of Database Properties to the Debug window.

```
Private Sub EnumerateDatabaseProperties()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim p1 As DAO.Property, s1 As String
    For Each p1 In CurrentDb.Properties
        s1 = p1.Name
        s1 = s1 & "=" & p1.value
        Debug.Print s1
    Next p1
End Sub
```

Do realize that a database property might not show up in the output if it doesn't exist, rather than just showing up in the output with no value.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't see your answer before I re asked in a different format.  I've already tried this and found no property probably needs to be created.  But I need to know the proper property name to make it work.

Comment: As posted above, the property name is: CustomRibbonId The value of it should be a string that is the name of your custom ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

First we need a robust method for setting DB properties.

```
Public Sub SetCurrentDBProperty(ByVal propertyName As String, ByVal newValue As Variant, Optional ByVal prpType As Long = dbText)
    Dim thisDBs As Database
    Set thisDBs = CurrentDb
    Dim wasFound As Boolean
        
    ' Look for property in collection
    Dim thisProperty As Object ' DAO.Property
    For Each thisProperty In thisDBs.Properties
        If thisProperty.Name = propertyName Then
            ' Check for matching type
            If thisProperty.Type <> prpType Then
                ' Remove so we can add it back in with the correct type.
                thisDBs.Properties.Delete propertyName
                Exit For
            End If

            wasFound = True
            
            ' Skip when no change is required
            If thisProperty.Value = newValue Then
                Exit For
            Else
                ' Update value
                thisProperty.Value = newValue
            End If
        End If
    Next thisProperty
    
    If Not wasFound Then
        ' Add new property
        Set thisProperty = thisDBs.CreateProperty(propertyName, prpType, newValue)
        thisDBs.Properties.Append thisProperty
    End If
End Sub
```

Then given an example ribbon name of `Runtime` you could call the property setter like this:

```
Public Sub SetRuntimeRibbon()
    SetCurrentDBProperty "CustomRibbonID", "Runtime"
End Sub
```