# Access: Load and apply Custom Ribbon via VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I need to set some buttons for RunTime users.

I was created USysRibbon table, inserted XML and tested via Database options. All works fine.

But I need load Custom ribbon via VBA custom function. This function will be executed via AutoExec macro (after user login and user id as temp variable is set).

Please help me to create simple VBA to call LoadCustomUI function and get XML from table (in that table is ID, RibbonName and RibbonXML) and apply to user interface.

Thank you.

Comment: The ribbon data in `USysRibbons` is loaded automatically. You don't need to call `LoadCustomUI` unless you are dynamically generating the ribbon XML in VBA. The step you are missing is setting `CustomRibbonID` to match the name of your ribbon in the table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what are the DB.Properties(??) variables? Specifically setting the default ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925981/what-are-the-db-properties-variables-specifically-setting-the-default-ribbo)

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you have created your ribbon table like this : http://www.accessribbon.de/en/?Access_-_Ribbons:Load_Ribbons_Into_The_Database:..._Using_The_System_Table_USysRibbons

Let's say:

1. your AutoExec macro execute the function `Start_App()`
2. You have in your table a record with RibbonName="MyRibbon1"

Create a module with the following code

```
' This variable handle your ribbon name, so if you have several Ribbons in your table, you adapt this constant to match the current Ribbon

Public Const APP_RIBBON As String = "MyRibbon1"


Public Function Start_app()

    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    LoadRibbons

    ' do anything else you need in the Start_app    

Exit_Sub:
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.DESCRIPTION, vbExclamation, "An error " & Err.Number & " occured !"
        Debug.Print Err.Number
        Resume Exit_Sub
    End If

End Function


Private Function LoadRibbons()

        On Error GoTo Error1

        Dim RS As dao.Recordset

        Set RS = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM USysRibbon ")

     Do Until RS.EOF

         If RS("RibbonName").value = APP_RIBBON Then
              ' Ribbon found: Load it and exit
            Application.LoadCustomUI APP_RIBBON, RS("RibbonXML").value
            Exit Do
        End If

         RS.MoveNext

     Loop

Error1_Exit:

     On Error Resume Next
     RS.Close
     Set RS = Nothing
     Exit Function

Error1:

     Select Case Err
         Case 32609
         ' Ribbon already loaded, do nothing and exit
     Case Else
         MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.DESCRIPTION, vbCritical, "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
     End Select

     Resume Error1_Exit

 End Function
```

Note that you have an additional thing to do: the first time you run the code, the Ribbon will not show. You have to go in the **options** / **current database** and in the combo box `Ribbon Name:` select the ribbon. If you have run the code once, your MyRibbon1 should appear in the combo box

Comment: Thank you. But I can not set to open custiom ribbon in options / current database. In this case, full Access users has hidden all Ribbon controls. I need Custom ribbon for Runtime user only. No for admins with full access version. I have login form and login macros for setting user IDs. It set temp variable with user ID - with this I can work in session.

Answer (score 0):

In Order to change the ribbon name in current database options, just use the following :

```
CurrentDb.Properties("CustomRibbonID") = Me.theRibbon
```

`theRibbon` is the Ribbon name in `usysRibbons` table