# Customized Ribbons in Access

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, ribbon-control

looking for assistance. I've created 2 customized ribbons in the 'uSysRibbons' table. One resets the ribbon so nothing other than the file menu is visible.  The other returns the Ribbon to a default state.

I am needing to find a dynamic way of switching between the two depending on criteria that is set on Form Open.

So in other words something like this:

If  = true
Show customRibbon1
Else
Show customRibbon2
End if

I can set the the XML statement so that it loads into a OnRibbonLoad function, but I can't seem to then switch the ribbon based on the above criteria.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: What actual code did you attempt? I think what you need is in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.Application.LoadCustomUI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access: Load and apply Custom Ribbon via VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926784/access-load-and-apply-custom-ribbon-via-vba)